# Does Pex support windows phone 7 unit testing?

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing, pex

As I known, Pex supports the following two kinds of framework settings `PexAssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Settings -- 1
[assembly: PexAssemblySettings(TestFramework = "VisualStudioUnitTest")]
```

And

```
// Microsoft.Pex.Framework.Settings -- 2
[assembly: PexAssemblySettings(TestFramework = "VisualStudioUnitTestSilverlight")]
```

Is there any framework settings for windows phone 7?

If we use this setting #2 (TestFramework = "VisualStudioUnitTestSilverlight")

We got exception when we test classes which are Windows Phone OS special( e.g. "Microsoft.Devices.DeviceType").

The exception info is:
Message = "未能加载文件或程序集“Microsoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e”或它的某一个依赖项。The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You need to run your unit-tests in the emulator, no matter how you put it.

Comment: Is there any tool like "Pex and Moles" that can automatically emit unit tests for windows phone 7 development?

Comment: No, as the emitting support is near non-existent.